# a Regex match where one word appears on a line without another

Tags: c#, regex

I have been through a lot of examples and posts for this, none of them are working.
I want to find a line where one word appears and the other does not.
Working in `C#` with `Regex.IsMatch` – I pulled in a file and am running the regex on that file.

```
Match if "WriteLine" found without "ALLOWEDTAG".
```

This would NOT match:

```
Console.WriteLine("FOUND line without"); // ALLOWEDTAG
```

This would match

```
Console.WriteLine("FOUND line without"); // anything.
```

I have tried the following:

```
TagRegex = @"WriteLine.^((?!ALLOWED TAG).)*$";
TagRegex = @"\<WriteLine(:Wh+~(ALLOWED_TAG):w=:q)+:Wh*";
TagRegex = @"^(?!.[\s\S]*ALLOWEDTAG).[\s\S]*WriteLine.*$";
TagRegex = @"^(?!.*ALLOWEDTAG).*WriteLine.*$";
TagRegex = @"((?!ALLOWEDTAG).)*WriteLine.*";
TagRegex = @"((.*WriteLine.*)(?!.*ALLOWEDTAG.*))";
```

What's up?

Comment: Why not just use `string.Contains`?  `line.Contains("WriteLine") && !line.Contains("ALLOWETAG")`

Comment: @juharr, the OP is not concerned about `"ALLOWETAG"`. :-) Even with the correction, however, what if `"HALLOWEDTAG"` were present? I do think your basic suggestion of checking for the presence of one string and the absence of another is a good one, as it permits the use of two simple regex's: `/\bWriteLine\b/` and `/\bALLOWEDTAG\b/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's why I asked.  The OP might know that there is no possible substring matching issues and a regular expression wouldn't be needed, as they are often not "simple" for everybody.

Comment: @juharr, 16 Feb 15: "Definitely no substring matching issues!"; 16 Feb 16: "We've got a substring matching issue".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead based regex. Add the multiline modifier `(?m)` when you're trying to match multiple lines.

```
@"(?m)^(?!.*?\bALLOWEDTAG\b).*?\bWriteLine\b.*"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pR8uW0/2)

Comment: yep, thanks.. I thought that he was trying to check with a single line input.

Comment: Thank you both ( Avinash and hwnd) So much!

Answer (score 2):

Your fourth attempt at this is simply fine, you just need the [**multi-line**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#multiline) modifier enabled which causes `^` and `$` anchors to match the begin/end of each line.

```
@"(?m)^(?!.*ALLOWEDTAG).*WriteLine.*$"
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/bDyVST)